# Which Web Scraping extraction method is better?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I have this code:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


ITEM_HTML = '''<html><head></head><body>
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <article class="product_pod">
            <div class="image_container">
                    <a href="catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html"><img src="media/cache/2c/da/2cdad67c44b002e7ead0cc35693c0e8b.jpg" alt="A Light in the Attic" class="thumbnail"></a>
            </div>
                <p class="star-rating Three">
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                </p>
            <h3><a href="catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html" title="A Light in the Attic">A Light in the ...</a></h3>
            <div class="product_price">
        <p class="price_color">£51.77</p>
<p class="instock availability">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
        In stock
</p>
    <form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-loading-text="Adding...">Add to basket</button>
    </form>
            </div>
    </article>
</li>
</body></html>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(ITEM_HTML, 'html.parser')


def find_item_price():
    locator = 'article.product_pod p.price_color'
    item_price = soup.select_one(locator).string

    pattern = '£([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'
    matcher = re.search(pattern, item_price)
    return float(matcher.group(1))


def find_item_price_way_two():
    locator = 'article.product_pod p.price_color'
    item_price = soup.select_one(locator).string

    item_price_symbol = item_price
    item_price_int = float(item_price.strip('£'))
    return item_price_int


print(find_item_price())
print(find_item_price_way_two())
```

#### Teacher solution:

- Now as you can see in the function `find_item_price()`, my tutor has taught me a way to extract the price of the item from the above `HTML` code. He first imports the `re` module and uses it to create a range of numbers in the `pattern` variable. But before he actually did that, he challenged the students to try it themselves

#### My solution:

- But when *I* tried it *myself*, I used the solution in the `find_item_price_way_two()` function. I used the `.strip()` method and removed the Euro Sign. The answer is exactly the same as the teacher's. It is a float, it is manipulatable.

I agree the teacher is also correct but it seems to me that my code is shorter, simpler, much more readable, and clean.

Can anyone please provide a list of pros and cons of each of the above two methods?  Is one more effiecient?  Easier to maintain?  Other pros/cons??

Thank you.

Comment: Definitely ***ask your teacher*** for pros and cons of each approach.  Explain you want to learn and understand better how to choose an approach to a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teacher solution like me better, becouse it's universally. Regular Expression is very strong and simple tool, especially in parsing. Besides that, your teacher want to teach you and show popular cases. Usually programmes use `re` for such cases. You may have already had experience using RE on previous lessons and your tutor wanted you to remember.

`.strip()` method removes passed symbol only on sides. This will not help you when you have a more complicated case.

In this case you need to remove only first character. You can use a slice for this.

```
def find_item_price_way_three():
    locator = 'article.product_pod p.price_color'
    item_price = soup.select_one(locator).string
    return float(item_price[1:])
```

I thing it's best way in this case, but remember that RE is more general solution.

Comment: Ask your teach what he thinks about this way for this case.

Comment: Actually, It is a udemy course so I mistakenly skipped the regex tutorial and I was soo confused that he didn't explain the `re` module. But then I saw it and now I know which one is better. Thanks for your help tho.